# Words with an overlap prefix

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be some alphabet of distinct symbols, say $\mathcal{A} = \{a, f, l\}$. Let $\mathcal{A}^*$ be the set of all finite words over $\mathcal{A}$.
An *overlap* is any word of the form $xyxyx$, where $x$ and $y$ are subwords and $x$ is non-empty.
A word is *periodic* (or a *proper power*) if $w = x^n$ for some word $x$ and some $n>1$.

For example, $alfalfa$ is an overlap, with $x = a$ and $y = lf$. The word $alfalfalf$ is periodic.

Note that $alfalfa$ has a cyclic rotation $lfalfaa$ which has no overlap prefix.

> If $w \in \mathcal{A}^*$ is aperiodic, is there a cyclic rotation of $w$ that has no overlap prefix?

An aperiodic word need not have a cyclic rotation with no periodic prefix. For example, every cyclic rotation of $w = (faa)^3 fa$ has a periodic prefix.

Comment: In your definition of an overlap, you certainly assume that $x$ and $y$ are not simultaneously empty, but do you allow $y$ (or $x$) to be empty words?

Comment: Certainly $x$ should be nonempty. In fact, because we are happy to pass to a prefix, wlog $x$ has length 1 (write $x = x'x''$, where $x'$ has length 1, and note that $x'(x''y)x'(x''y)x'$ is a prefix of $xyxyx$). If $y$ is empty but $x$ is nonempty then we're talking about cubes. I am happy to consider all cubes to be overlaps.

Comment: I also suppose you want to prove your statement for sufficiently long words. Indeed, the word $a$, for instance, has no periodic prefix.

Comment: Actually I am not aware of counterexamples of any length. The letter $a$ is not a counterexample: it satisfies my hypothesis (aperiodic) and conclusion (there is a cyclic rotation (the trivial one) that has no overlap prefix).

Comment: Sorry, I misread your conjecture.

Comment: @SeanEberhard sorry if i'm being slow, but what's the point of the last two sentences of your post?

Comment: @joriki Normally I would agree with you, but in this case I am using $a$, $l$, and $f$ as generators similar to $x$, $y$, and $z$, and the play on the English word "alfalfa" is just for fun.

Comment: @mathworker21 Those sentences relate to a natural stronger guess: that you can always rotate an aperiodic word so that it has no square prefix. For example $aaf$ can be rotated to $afa$, which has no square prefix. If a word has no square prefix then it certainly has no overlap prefix (because an overlap begins with a square). However, the stronger guess is wrong.

Comment: @SeanEberhard: Ah, I see.